# copy or yank from line x until line y

Tags: cut-copy-paste

I know about `:yN` for example , `:y10` , yank 10 lines from current line.

I need to yank from line 73 until line 81, How can I do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
:73,81yank
```

Ex commands usually take ranges and `yank` is no exception.